# C# Excel Interop xl.XlDirection Enum

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I am exploring the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library.  I want to delete a row from a sheet.  I have found many resources that say to do:

```
rng.Delete(xl.XDirection.xlUp);
```

I noticed that using xlUp,  xlDown, xlToLeft, and xlToRight, and leaving the method parameter blank all produce the same result, so what is purpose of Enum XlDirection.  The Documentation says "Specifies the direction in which to move." but it doesn't seem to be moving in any direction, just deleting.

Here is my full code:

```
namespace ExcelTrial
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string workbookPath = $@"H:\Practice\TestBook.xlsx";

            xl.Application xlApp = new xl.Application();
            xl.Workbook wb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath);
            xl.Worksheet ws = wb.Worksheets[1];

            xl.Range rng = ws.Rows[9];
            rng.Select();

            //This all produce the same result.
            // What is the difference?
            rng.Delete(xl.XlDirection.xlToLeft);
            rng.Delete(xl.XlDirection.xlToRight);
            rng.Delete(xl.XlDirection.xlDown);
            rng.Delete(xl.XlDirection.xlUp);
            rng.Delete();

            wb.Save();
            wb.Close();
            xlApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be using the wrong enum? Delete method: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.delete Enums Used: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldeleteshiftdirection

Comment: The left and up values of the xlDeleteShiftDirection have the same value of the xlDirection toLeft and Up. Per the documentation, if not specified it uses the shape of the range to specify behavior. If you are deleting rows, xlToLeft won't do anything other than default because it's a row, not a column. Usually when I delete a row in xl the default behavior moves the other rows up. So maybe changing the shape will provide different behavior.

Comment: If you delete a whole row manually in Excel, you'll see you get no prompt asking you how you want to "fill in" the hole left by the deletion.  In comparison, if you delete a single cell you'll get the prompt.